# cxf generated wsdl: change soap address location protocol to https

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cxf, spring-ws

I use a spring boot ws application together with apache cxf to provide a SOAP web service. All configured URLs use relative paths, so that the application can be used with flexible deployments.

In production environment, the application is running behind a load balancer and forces clients to use https. But the generated wsdl keeps its **http** protocol although the wsdl itself is exposed using **https**.

This is the spring endpoint configuration:

```
@Bean
  public Endpoint endpoint() {
    EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(springBus(), requestStatusApplicationService());
    RequestStatusReceiverService requestStatusReceiverService = requestStatusReceiverService();
    endpoint.setServiceName(requestStatusReceiverService.getServiceName());
    endpoint.setWsdlLocation(requestStatusReceiverService.getWSDLDocumentLocation().toString()); // also a relative path
    endpoint.publish("/relative-path-endpoint");
    return endpoint;
  }
```

How can I adjust the generated wsdl, so that it switches to https?
Or better: is it possible to force the protocol to use the same like the exposed wsdl itself?

Best,
Lars

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have the same problem :D

Answer (score 2):

I also faced a similar issue in my project, and I solved it by using spring boot parameters. We have a ngnix server which takes the requests and forwards to back-end machines having spring boot applications.

Added following parameters in ngnix configuration.

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Scheme https;
```

Later, added following parameters in spring boot application

```
server.tomcat.remote-ip-header=x-forwarded-for
server.tomcat.protocol-header=x-forwarded-proto
```

After this server started appending https to the URL.

Comment: I dont think the server.tomcat.* properties are really needed, if you just fix the proxy headers, are they? Here, it seems to work without them.

Answer (score 2):

In your spring-boot application, if you are using cxf framework then you can add your custom interceptor to pass on the custom url.

```
public class MyInInterceptor extends AbstractInDatabindingInterceptor {

    private String url;

    public CustomInInterceptor(String url) {
        super(Phase.USER_STREAM);
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
        message.put("org.apache.cxf.request.url", url);
    }
}
```

You need to configure this interceptor like this in your config file.

```
EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(bus, communicationPortTypeImpl);
List<Interceptor<? extends Message>> interceptors = new ArrayList<>();
interceptors.add(new MyInInterceptor(endpointUrl));
endpoint.setInInterceptors(interceptors);
endpoint.publish("/myEndPoint");
```